# Installing Ubuntu server without a user account?

Tags: ubuntu

Anyone know of of a way to install Ubuntu without adding a user account?  I can see the utility for this on a desktop install, but on a server install, it's really unnecessary (for me at least) since all user accounts are provisioned in LDAP.

Ideally, I want to install with only the *root* account which gets locked down via *ansible* later on.

[image]

Comment: Not a regular Ubuntu user, but I believe you have to use the automatic installation method for this, with a preseed file. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch04s06.html. Oh, and of course you could also delete an user with Ansible.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using Ansible to delete the account, however other admins using my playbook don't always provision the account with the same user so I run across server installs sometimes which have "installer" accounts on them.  I haven't found a good way to tell ansible to nuke all accounts except for root and "system" accounts (mysql, cron, uucp, etc). Looking into the preseed link.. thanks

Comment: Yes, deleting "everything except" isn't that simple in Ansible unfortunately. Another thing (speaking from experience here and you probably know that anyway): If you have only LDAP-provisioned users, make sure that you can login as root (IIRC `root` is disabled in a stock Ubuntu install). If LDAP auth fails and you can't log in as root, things get complicated.

Comment: I usually sudo and set the root pass after first boot to enable it. Is there another way? `nss_initgroups_ignoreusers`? Learned that one the hard way long ago. Thanks for the reminder however.

Comment: `however other admins using my playbook don't always provision the account with the same user ` - The first account Ubuntu creates is almost always has a UID of 1000.  So you could almost certainly find it with getent.  `ansible -i localhost, localhost -m getent -a 'database=passwd key=1000'`